# Wordpress Cloudflare Cache - tengo que apretar f5 cada vez que entro a mi pagina

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Hola estoy teniendo un problema que es que he recreado una pagina web, donde el desarrolador anterior le puso cloudflare, y he desactivado todo de cloudflare para no tener problemas en la actualizacion de las noticias, ya que no debe guardar cache, el las guardaba y no actualizaba las ultimas noticias, pero yo intento resolverlo, que se valla mostrando las nuevas noticias sin apretar f5.. que arecomiendan que haga.

Answer (score 1):

Es posible que se esté especificando cache en mas sitios. Mira en el inspeccionador de elementos > network > (el primer elemento de la pagina) > el Response headers > Cache-Control.

Puedes probar con Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0